# Use filter and map methods to capitalize the first letter of certain elements within an array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I am trying to accomplish capitalizing the first letter of certain elements within an array.  I am needing to skip the elements that begin with the letter c.  I am also required to use the filter and map methods.  I viewed the documentation at MDN and I am at a loss.  This is for school, so I really need to understand why the code works; I am not just looking for the answer.  Here is my html:

```
<div><strong>Sorted Fruit:</strong> <span id="sorted-fruit"></span></div>
<div><strong>Capitalized Fruit without Cs:</strong> <span id="capitalized-fruit"></span></div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
// (1) Iterate through each fruit type and write it to the console 
//      using a for loop.
// (2) Use Array's methods "sort" and "join" to print an alphabetically 
//      sorted comma delimited list of fruit in the span with id "sorted-fruit"
// (3) Use ECMAScript 5 Array methods "filter" and "map" and Array method 
//      "join" to print out a comma delimited list of fruit that are 
//      capitalized (just the first letters); skip those that contain the 
//      letter "c" in them.

(function() {

    var fruit = [
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "peach",
        "cherry",
        "pear",
        "apricot",
        "banana",
        "guava",
        "melon"
    ];

    fruit.sort();
    var myFruit = fruit.join(', ');
    for (i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
         console.log(myFruit);
         }

    document.getElementById('sorted-fruit').innerHTML = myFruit;
    // Your code goes here ...

}());
```

Comment: you just posted the assignment..... dont u think that it is bit lazy to do that, instead of work on it?? vote for close

Comment: I posted my assignment but I also included my work.  I was able to complete tasks 1 and 2.  I also spent about an hour doing research and attempting to solve this on my own before I posted here.  Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: my apologies, I've totally misread your comments, i was confused by this part "// Your code goes here ..." i thought that is the only problem not solved by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your part 3 solution:

```
// Filter out entries with the letter 'c'
fruit = fruit.filter(function (el) {
    return el.indexOf('c') === -1;
});

// Capitalize the first letter of all remaining strings
fruit = fruit.map(function(string){ 
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
});
```

But I want you to take apart this solution and figure out what it is doing.

Comment: He got part 1 and 2, so what the heck. I was struggling once too. Plus he was honest. "I viewed the documentation at MDN and I am at a loss. This is for school"

Comment: Not sure why kanJi is even posting on this thread.  Has a very YouTube hate feel to it lol

Comment: Drake, thank you for your feedback.  I really appreciate it.  I feel pretty good about whats going on here: 

fruit = fruit.map(function (string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    });

It makes sense to me that charAt(0) (thats basically the index value of the first letter in the string, right?) and then calling toUpperCase().  string.slice(1) is basically saying to stop once we reach index 1 of whatever string we are working on in the array, yes?

Comment: I am not really understanding this:

fruit = fruit.filter(function (el) {
    return el.indexOf('c') === -1;
});

I am confused when we pass el as the argument into our function.  How are we defining the value of el?  This:  return el.indexOf('c') makes sense to me, but why are we comparing it to -1?

Again, i really appreciate your help Drakes!

Comment: @DrewTuzson you do not need to pass el, filter works like this ( "el" is just an element in your array(the function iterates over your array and el is just the next element init), next el.indexOf('c') === -1; this will return true only if the word do not start with "c" character, you can read here - > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: @DrewTuzson Thank you for examining this answer and asking questions. kanJi is pretty much right. The -1 is returned when indexOf cannot find the 'c'. If it could find that letter, then it returns the position of that letter in the string. So, we filter or remove those trings which do not contain 'c'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to shorten what you need to write in code arrow functions are great!

```
// To capitalize the first letter of remaining words, using 'w' as the variable for each word
const fruit = fruit.map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1));
```

```js
var fruit = [
  "apple",
  "orange",
  "peach",
  "cherry",
  "pear",
  "apricot",
  "banana",
  "guava",
  "melon"
]
const fruitChanged = fruit.map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1));

console.log(fruitChanged)
```

Also the map array method is great if you are going to iterate through an array.
MDN - Array Method: Map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map